# How to put comma in a number excel

Tags: excel

I have two numbers : 7,8 and 6,8.
When I multiply these numbers I get #VALUE!. I know, this happens because excel thinks, these numbers are strings because of the comma. But i cannot use separator . (point) because in my task, numbers are with , (comma). I tried different number functions, but all of them converts numbers with point (eg. 7.8 , 6.8). What I need to do? Thanks for advices.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")` will remove the comma and replace it with a full-stop

Comment: "But i cannot use separator . (point) because in my task, numbers are with , (comma)" Can you explain this more? Typically number separators are defined by the operating system's regional settings.  Should all numbers you're using in every program use a comma instead of a decimal?

Answer (score 0):

To multiply them as whole numbers, use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")*SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","")
```

to display 5304.  To multiply as decimal fractionals, use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")*SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",".")
```

to display 53.04

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced Options

- Deselect "Use System Separators"
- Fill in `comma` for decimal and `space` for thousands

[image]

Now you can do it:

[image]

This will make the change for all Excel documents.

An alternative, which will make the change throughout your system, would be to change your Windows Regional settings the same way.  Be sure to change both number and currency if you do that.