# How to change period symbol from point to comma in excel

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I need a help regarding formatting the column in **Excel**.

How can i convert `0.0000000000e+000` to `0,0000000000e+000`?

(Change period symbol from `.` to `,`)

Thank you

Comment: You could try [like so](https://www.howtogeek.com/245510/how-to-change-excels-decimal-separators-from-periods-to-commas/)

Comment: Check this answer: [How to put comma in a number excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416877/7519419)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: [Change the decimal point to a comma or vice versa](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/change_the_decimal_point_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html)

Change your **decimal separator** to `,`

Comment: @Ketan I am glad that I could help you.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, @KetanSahu, please, mark it as correct, so the question will be closed and may be useful for future users.